# How to add Objects to ArrayList

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm unable to add Objects to my `ArrayList` which I'm receiving from the API endpoint. I'm trying to make  `JsonArray` from `JSONObject`.

```
mJsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            mJsonArray=response.getJSONArray("articles");
            for(int i=0;i<mJsonArray.length();i++){
                mJsonObject=mJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                model = new Model();
                model.setTitle(mJsonObject.getString("title"));
                model.setAuthor(mJsonObject.getString("author"));
                model.setDescription(mJsonObject.getString("description"));

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + model.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // returns 0

                mModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSON as well in the post? What's the output if you log `mJsonArray` & `mJsonObject` in the code? Do they receive data accordingly from the API Endpoint?

Comment: check my answer , it's way easier than your approach

Comment: @ahmedaljubair  actaually i m getting all the data in try catch and it will be added in ArrayList , but when i access data from list (out side the try catch block or anywhere in code ) the size still return 0 while i declare Array list as global variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Gson`](https://github.com/google/gson) library which will do the hard work for you.

for example:

this is your json `String` :

```
"[{'Title':'admin','Name':'eddie'},{'Title':'manager','Name':'frank'}]"
```

and this is your POJO:

```
 class Model {
    public String Title;
    public String Name;
}
```

and use it as follow:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
    ArrayList<Model> i = g.fromJson("[{'Title':'title','Name':'name'},{'Title':'title','Name':'name'}]", new ArrayList<Model>().getClass());
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(i.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the response with `object.optString("code")` or else you need POJO Class. I am referring solution one according to you

```
mJsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, ENDPOINT, null, 
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
try {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 200) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new 
                    JSONObject(response.body().string());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("data");
                    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                        db.clearData();
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.optJSONObject(i);
                        db.insertConfig(new ConfigModel(object.optInt("id"), object.optString("code"), object.optString("value"), object.optString("createdAt"), object.optString("updatedAt")));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                utility.logger(ex.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Rahaman   actaually i m getting all the data in try catch and it will be added in ArrayList , but when i access data from list (out side the try catch block or anywhere in code ) the size still return 0 while i declare Array list as global variable

Comment: have you solved your problem? Once I faced the same problem thn found that i need to iterate each object and add in ArrayList. If you did not find any solution thn i can look through my code and paste it here.